# The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-410

I have a web API2 application which is consumed by a third party application. When the application hits my end-point, my application send oAuth credentials for authentication and gets the results from the third party application.

Recently some of the transactions are failing and when i added some logs, i saw that the error: **The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone** is occurring for all failed transactions. Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this issue when I am calling my application. The following is the code that I am using. What could be the issue that is causing this error?

```
 public async Task<customerModel>  SendSigned(string url)
{
    customerModel customermodel = null;
    try
    {
        OAuthBase oauthBase = new OAuthBase();

        string oAuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthKey"];
        string oAuthSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthSecret"];
        string timestamp = oauthBase.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string nonce = oauthBase.GenerateNonce();
        string normalizedUrl;
        string normalizedRequestParameters;
        string sig = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauthBase.GenerateSignature(
            new Uri(url), oAuthKey, oAuthSecret, string.Empty, string.Empty,
            "GET", timestamp, nonce, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters));
        string requestUrl = String.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters, sig);

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
           myXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
           customermodel = GetCustomerInformation(response);
        }

        return await Task.Run(() => customermodel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       _logger.Error("Error in SendSigned method", ex.InnerException);
        return customermodel;
    }
}
```

Comment: We are now seeing the same thing. Only 1 user gets 410 on one of our endpoints, but it works file for all other users. Long shot, did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of `410` is ***The target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent*** based on
[this](https://httpstatuses.com/410) link (similar to a 404)

I would suggest you to think about recent changes you made to your

1. API signatures
2. Folder restructure/reorganization of assets/resources
3. Routing changes
4. Rename of resources

Comment: This issue is happening intermittently and not all the time. So it looks like the folder structure/API signatures are the same

Comment: use Postman to see the actual response message.